# Crazy behaviour with UIViewController inits in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I'm trying to add simple initialiser to a `UIViewController` in `Swift`. So far it has been very frustrating...

First I tried adding it as a convenience init:

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var model: UIImage

    convenience init(model: UIImage){

        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.model = model

    }
....
```

If I do this, the compiler forces me to implement required `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. I checked the definition of the `UIViewController` class and there's no such requirement, but anyway.

To make things worse, the compiler complains that the `self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` call has an erroneous extra argument in `bundle:`. Again, I checked the class definition and the initialiser signature requires both parameters.

So I decided to make it a designated init. It's not what I want, as I don't want to lose all the superclass initialisers.

Now it seems to be happy with the `self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` call, but it still insists that I implement `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

Any ideas of what's going on? I can't make head or tails of this...

Answer (score 3):

The error messages are indeed confusing, but I think they come from the fact that
if the `model` property has no default value then the required initializers are no longer
inherited from the superclass. With an optional (or implicitly unwrapped optional) property
(which has the default value `nil`) your code compiles:

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var model: UIImage!

    convenience init(model: UIImage) {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.model = model
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `model` property to be optional, don't make it optional. Sure, it's a bitch to have to implement [`initWithCoder:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder:), but it's better to have rock-solid, secure code.

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {
    var model: UIImage

    init(model: UIImage) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This ensures that the only way an instance of `ImageViewController` can be created is by calling `initWithModel:` and therefore guarantees that `model` will always have a nonoptional value.

Maybe in the future, Apple will add a convenient way of doing this, but for now, I must sacrifice convenience for control.